# Pandas to_numeric with option errors=ignore does not convert to float

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to convert pandas series from object to float but keep other strings as it is.

Here is the code snippet :-

```
In [37]: df = pd.DataFrame(['-1.0', 'hello', '0.5'])

In [38]: df[0]
Out[38]: 
0   -1.0
1  hello
2    0.5
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

What I want is this :-

```
In [43]: df[0]
Out[43]: 
0     -1.0
1    hello
2      0.5
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

I tried to use this but it converts `hello` to `NaN` which I don't want :-

```
In [41]: pd.to_numeric(df[0], errors='coerce')
Out[41]: 
0   -1.0
1    NaN
2    0.5
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

I tried putting `errors='ignore'` but it doesn't convert object to float :-

```
In [44]: pd.to_numeric(df[0], errors='ignore')
Out[44]: 
0     -1.0
1    hello
2      0.5
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Could someone please help me out with this ?

Thanks.

Comment: The last result is expected operation, you've elected not to convert so the dtype becomes object, you can't have a dtype of float if the types are mixed, a string is not a float

Comment: Thanks, Basically I wanted to write dataframe to excel df.to_excel but the issue is - it writes all numbers as text rather than numeric. Hence I wanted to keep the original strings as it is but keep all numbers as numeric instead of text in excel. Could you please help me how to keep numbers as numbers instead of text while using df.to_excel but also keep other strings as strings ?

Comment: What's the next step in what you plan on doing with that series? You can't have a string defined as a float, but that may not matter... depending on what comes next.

Answer (score 0):

To get the result you want:

```
In [29]:
df1 = pd.to_numeric(df[0], errors='coerce')
df1

Out[29]:
0   -1.0
1    NaN
2    0.5
Name: 0, dtype: float64

In [32]:
df1 = df1.fillna(df[0])
df1.iloc[0]

Out[32]:
-1.0

In [33]:
df1.iloc[1]

Out[33]:
'hello'

In [34]:
df1.iloc[-1]

Out[34]:
0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a dirty hack to accomplish that what you want:

```
In [73]: new = pd.to_numeric(df[0], errors='coerce')

In [74]: new
Out[74]:
0   -1.0
1    NaN
2    0.5
Name: 0, dtype: float64

In [75]: new2 = new.combine_first(df[0])

In [76]: new2
Out[76]:
0       -1   # element type: float
1    hello   # element type: str
2      0.5   # element type: float
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

you can apply numerical math **to numeric elements only**

```
In [78]: new2.iloc[[0,2]] += 1

In [79]: new2
Out[79]:
0        0
1    hello
2      1.5
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

**BUT BE AWARE:**

```
In [80]: new2 += 10
...
TypeError: must be str, not int
...
```